# Move bitlocked second drive to new system

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I am to receive a new laptop, and i need to move my second physical drive to the new machine.  The second drive is protected with bitlocker.  I do not have admin privs on the current machine, so i cannot turn off bitlocker.

This is a windows 7 machine.

What will happen if i simply put the second drive in the new machine?  Will i be able to access the contents?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you will not be able to access its contents. This is the entire point of Bitlocker.